# How to click on multiple buttons or link over depth using selenium with python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation

I am trying to **automate** the form filling and *accessing the details* (using selenium in python) for the same I have successfully submitted the button with values and got to the page. Now, I have a link/button on this page also and I just have to **click on** it, which might redirect me to the next page [url might be change and sometimes not] and I have to access the details from this page also. So, please give me some code references already worked around for you.

Comment: After redirecting to the page, you can fetch the current url and save that in a variable  and then navigate to that url which you have saved in variable and access details of that page. Hope it can help you.

Comment: what's the source code of your button?